# Python mock.patch.object with functool.partial bound arguments possible?

Tags: python, mocking, optional-parameters, monkeypatching, functools

How to solve this? Patch a objects method with another signature (eg. an additional argument. I've tried to bound the optional argument, but this does not seem to work. I can not use plain monkey patching here, since the the patched class is called under in a location where I can not patch it that way otherwise.

Any help appreciated.

```
import mock
import functools

# this class lives in another (unchangeable) module, __len__ method has to be patched
class ToOverride(object):
    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

# this code is changeable
def my_len(self, arg):
    return arg+1

my_len_bound = functools.partial(my_len, arg=1)

with mock.patch.object(ToOverride, '__len__', my_len_bound):
    inst = ToOverride()
    print len(inst) # expected output: 2
```

When invoking the context mock.patch.object, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bfdb41d8628f> in <module>()
      1 with mock.patch.object(ToOverride, '__len__', my_len_bound):
      2     inst = ToOverride()
----> 3     print len(inst)

TypeError: my_len() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

But invoking my_len with None as first argument works as expected (print out 2).

Assuming it would be possible to simply monkey patch, it works, if **len** is called manually with the instance as first argument. But this is of course undesired:

```
ToOverride.__len__ = my_len_bound
inst = ToOverride()
print( inst.__len__(inst)) # 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question, but anyway: Instead of `functools.partial`, use [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod)

As in:

```py
from unittest import mock
import functools

class ToOverride(object):
    def __len__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

def my_len(self, arg):
    return arg+1

my_len_bound = functools.partialmethod(my_len, arg=1)

with mock.patch.object(ToOverride, '__len__', my_len_bound):
    inst = ToOverride()
    assert len(inst) == 2
```

Comment: Thanks for updating to this super old question. I believe back in the day there was no partialmethod. So this is now the best answer, I'd guess.

Comment: @marscher Thanks! Indeed, `partialmethod` was first introduced in python 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

By using a closure pattern, one can avoid using functools partial, which does not work for class methods.

```
def bind_arg(arg):
    def my_len(self, arg):
        return arg+1
    return my_len
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the str of call_args with the expected_call
e.g.

```
self.assertEqual(
            str(running_loop.run_in_executor.call_args),
            str(
                call(
                    process_pool.__enter__(),
                    functools.partial(my_fun, arg1, arg2),
                )
            ),
        )
```